# Filter item out of a PHP list

Tags: php, filter, concrete5-5.6

I have a form that currently displays check boxes from a range in an attribute on concrete 5.6. What I need to do is to take that list, but now filter out one item.
I want to filter out `mpdID` of `81`.
The code used to display is:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <strong><?php  echo t('Choose Day')?></strong>
    <?php
        if($price_dates){
            foreach($price_dates->dates as $break){
                ?>
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="checkbox" 
                           name="mdpID[]" 
                           value="<?=$break['mdpID']?>" 
                           <?php 
                               if($ticketID['mdpID'] == $break['mdpID']){
                                   echo 'checked';
                               }
                           ?>
                     /> 
                 <?=date('D M jS',strtotime($break['date']))?> - £
                 <?=$break['price']?>
                 </div>

                 <?php
              }
          }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you trying to return all items that are not of value 81?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

**Example**

```
  $mp_ids = [1,5,81,81,23];

  $mp_ids = array_filter($mp_ids, function($value){
    return $value != 81;
  });
```

If you just do this above the view, then you can keep this logic out of your view and have things a lot cleaner.

A lot of the business logic should be left out of the view, otherwise things will get cluttered fast.

Now `$mp_ids` will be an array containing any value but 81. You could wrap this into a function to make it more flexible.

**Custom Filter Function for IDs**

```
  function filter_ids($array_of_ids, $exclude) {
    return array_filter($array_of_ids, function($value) use ($exclude){
      return $value != $exclude;
    });
  }

  filter_ids($mp_ids, 81);
  // returns array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(5) [4]=> int(23) }
  // return the data to your view to loop and generate the checkboxes
```

This is just a simple example, and could definitely be improved upon. But should give you an idea on where to go from here to give you more flexibility.

**Performance**

This would improve your performance on the foreach loop as it's only looping through items that it should output, and not having to constantly check if it should or should not.

Comment: The performance is pretty much lost because you are looping through the data once for filtering and again for display, HOWEVER, depending on the application it may be more prudent to remove unnecessary entries from the array prior to display.

Comment: Yeah, it may be better to just exclude the entry from his initial query when fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) directly after your `foreach` block begins. Something like this:

```
foreach block...

if ($break['mdpID'] == 81) {
    continue;
}
```